# How to bypass default aries jndi lookup in karaf

Tags: java, osgi, ibm-mq, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to lookup for a connectionFactory in a code which is deployed as part of osgi bundle in servicemix (karaf)

```
final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiContext = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
jndiContext.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
jndiContext.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
jndiContext.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, pJndiLDAPserver);
ctx = new InitialContext(jndiContext);
ConnectionFactory lResult = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(pJndiCFname);
```

The issue I am facing is -

1. when I do a ctx.lookup("xyz") - It gives me a object of javax.naming.Reference instead of MQconnectionFactory. (The same code works perfectly fine as standalone java application)
2. Also, ctx = new InitialContext(jndiContext) gives me an object of InitialContext with defaultInitContext as -
   org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext. Ideally it should give me defaultInitiContext as LdapCtx (as my provider url is a Ldap server)

I have the following dependency in my pom.xml -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>java</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>prereq</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.commonservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2se</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>allclientprereqs</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nls</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>nls</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>prereq</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.msg.client.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>wmq</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.csg.npms.pilatus</groupId>
        <artifactId>pilatus-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m09</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the same com.ibm dependency has been installed as part of karaf bundles.

So, therefore w.r.t abouve point 2, how can I bypass default jndi aries lookup in Karaf (org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext), so that it gives me LdapContextFactory Object instead of DelegateContext. Am I missing any jars as part of mq in karaf.

Comment: Which features do you install in karaf?
The error shows you have not installed the jms api. Tyically this API is installed when you install a jms client like ActiveMQ.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer .. you pushed Q for "requires editing"... could you please help OP pointing in the right direction what is lacking or change it yourself? (ps.: no need to reply to me cuz /I'm not even a beginner on this topic).

Comment: @ChristianSchneider - I have installed jndi and jms feature in karaf. The main issue is the osgi bundles are not able to find ibm mq and javax classes on its path.

Comment: IBM MQ might be a bit difficult to get working. The last time I tried it took me quite some effort. I read that at some point IBM started to produce bundles .. so I hope it is easier now but I do not have newer experiences with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the key part of the error:

```
Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.qpid.jms.client [464](R 464.8)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms (version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

This says that the bundle named `org.apache.qpid.jms.client` cannot be resolved because it imports the package `javax.jms` but there is no other bundle that exports the package `javax.jms`. In OSGi, every import must be matched by an export of that package. Additionally there is a version constraint: you need version `[1.1.0, 2.0.0)`, i.e at least 1.1.0 but less than 2.0.0.

I would suggest using the following bundle from Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.spec.javax.jms%7Cjboss-jms-api_1.1_spec%7C1.0.1.Final%7Cjar.

Comment: Hi Neil...the above maven bundle mentioned by you resolves this version error but then, it is unable to find any ibm mq jar. i.e. MQConnectionFactory mq = new MQConnectionFactory() now gives (some java linkage) exception. The issue which I am facing is how these javax-jms and ibm mq jars work with in integration with osgi bundles. If osgi is able to find these jars and classes correctly, it will never return me reference object on lookup of connection factory

Comment: Review this link. https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2018/01/09/developing-mq-java-applications-maven/

Comment: Even this didn't help ! :(

Comment: Anybody on karaf and mq jars integration ? need in urgent help !!

Comment: I have edited the question. Could anyone please assist.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how to bypass default jndi look up in karaf , something I myself am struggling with at the moment, trying to figure out how to get it to use an initial context factory that i need , i was able to get a MQ connection factory working by instantiating it directly via a bean in a blueprint, then you can name it and reference it from jndi as a normal service , like this:

```
 <bean id="wmqcf"  class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
     <property name="hostname" value="my.host">
     ...port, channel, queue manager, etc ...
</bean>

<service interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" ref="wmqcf">
    <service-properties>
       <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jms/wmqcf">
    </service-properties>
</srevice>
```

This way you don't need to worry about any bridges, pools, etc. Just a quick way to get a connection factory in your application for wmq.